# Can you tell DDR and DDR2 apart visually?

Tags: memory, ddr2, ddr

I'm getting a few old computers to take apart for parts soon.

Most of them are definitely using DDR2 RAM, but there is the possibility that one or two of them are using DDR RAM. Since these are quite old, the manuals have since been lost.

Is it possible to tell DDR and DDR2 RAM apart visually, and if so how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/hardware/ram_specification):

DDR memory modules have 184 pins and one notch: [image: DDR]

DDR2 modules have 240 pins and one notch. The notch on DDR2 DIMMs is in a different position than DDR DIMMs, and the pin density is slightly higher: [image: DDR2]

The site also contains specifications of the memory types...

Comment: Use the little photo shaped button to generate the tag information. It's similar to how the URLs are generated.  Also not sure of superuser prevents non-image extensions to be linked.

http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/lib/exe/detail.php/doc/appunti/hardware/ddr_sdram_400_1gb.jpg
http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/lib/exe/detail.php/doc/appunti/hardware/ddr2.jpg

Chop the end off the URLs.

Answer (score 25):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

DDR2 has more pins, and the notch is in a different place. In DDR, the notch should be close to the centre, wheras ddr2 is further off-centre. (But it's been a while since I've seen DDR ram, so I could be wrong!)

#### DDR2:

[image: DDR2]

#### DDR:

[image: DDR]

Comment: Bet you get more comment-kudos if you find pictures.

Comment: Better? :) (Did notice neither are really centered, though.