# How to identify different types of RAM

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you tell DDR and DDR2 apart visually?](https://superuser.com/questions/80092/can-you-tell-ddr-and-ddr2-apart-visually)

I would like to know how to identify different types of RAM like:

- SDRAM,
- Dynamic RAM,
- DDR,
- DDR2,
- DDR3,
- DDR4

Answer (score 1):

Usually the notches will tell you. Compare a few in person and it's not hard to tell, although the notch positions for DDR2, 3, etc can be a little harder to recognise from each other.

For DDR:

[image]

DDRAM will have two notches.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ultimate Memory Guide over at the Kingston memory website

http://www.kingston.com/tools/UMG/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the type of RAM by reading the fine print on either of the sticks, or by running [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/), which will also tell you if anything is wrong.

If you just wish to know what is on your computer, these sites will help:

- http://www.cpuid.com/
- http://www.crucial.com/

If you wish to know more, these sites provide easy-to-read tutorials and info:

- http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial122.html
- http://www.pcbuyerbeware.co.uk/RAM.htm
- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-kind-of-memory-does-my-computer-have-installed/

This link and related sites provide easy-to-follow how to's:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXlVvbgjrB0