# how to tell what memory is what

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you tell DDR and DDR2 apart visually?](https://superuser.com/questions/80092/can-you-tell-ddr-and-ddr2-apart-visually)

what dose 64mb and 128mb look like?

Comment: Memory like RAM? All the chips are different depending on what NANDs are attached, I have some ddr 256mb modules that look bigger than the ddr2 1 gig modules I have...

Comment: that is the info I'm looking for do you have pick or a web site that i can look at and identify the stuff that i have? I can us all the help i can get. Tanks drew

Comment: And this: http://superuser.com/questions/27006/how-to-check-ram-size-without-looking-at-motherboard - But really, this question could do with more details, like what type of RAM you're looking at

Comment: *SARCASM ON* We can't help you, this [link](http://www.spiritual-web.com/spiritual-development/channeling/pendulums/) can. *SARCASM OFF* What Kyle said is, that it's possible for a 256Mb Ram module to look larger than a modern 1G module.

Answer (score 3):

Memory of the same type (types being DDR, DDR2 and so on) will generally look alsmost exactly identical, with the only differences being that some sticks may have chips on both sides of the circuit board while others may not.  This is not a good indication of memory capacity though.

Often, aside from a sticker on the memory sticks, the only difference between them will be in the ident numbers on the memory chips.

Answer (score 2):

You can't look at memory and see how big it is, as long as it is not written onto. Just put it into a computer and look at the messages during boot up.

Or use software installed. When using windows right click on My Computer -> Properties there is somewhere the amount of memory in the computer.

I guess, that is your question, as your question is rather unspecific and not tagged with anything helpful like the type of ram or your operating system if you have any. I do not even know, why i even bother to answer to that question.

Comment: sorry i have some scrap memory and have fond a place that are looking for specific one for resell I just do not know how to tell what they are if they do not have a sticker.

Comment: Yeah, there is the problem. Almost no one can tell how big a ram module is by looking at it. You will have to insert it into some computer and look at the boot messages to tell the difference. Even if you would have attached a picture we couldn't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If the sticks still have their stickers, you might identify them through the part-number.