# would ddr2 memory work in a motherboard with ddr3 standard?

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i7, ddr2

I have a machine built with 4 x Mushkin Enhanced Blackline 2GB 240-Pin DDR2 SDRAM DDR2 1066 (PC2 8500) Desktop Memory Model 991599. I'm thinking of upgrading to an Intel iCore 7 CPU that requires a motherboard with a socket type LGA 1155. The problem is that neither of the available motherboards that I found with that socket type have a DDR2 standard.

I'm looking to save the most money possible with my current components and that means trying to avoid buying new memory. Would the DDR2 memory work on such motherboards?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope - DDR2 and DDR3 are electrically different and not cross compatible.

Pic: DDR3 on the top. DDR2 below.

[image]

Edit: Nice diagram in this answer too: 
[Can you tell DDR and DDR2 apart visually?](https://superuser.com/questions/80092/can-you-tell-ddr-and-ddr2-apart-visually)

Comment: The connector isn't even the same form factor - you physically can't get them in the same slots because they're keyed differently.

Comment: Yep - just came back to add the pic...

Comment: Do you know if there's a motherboard with LGA 1155 and DDR2?

Comment: Not that I can find. You'd be limited to socket 775 / AM3 boards I believe, so you could consider a socket 775 quad core xeon or core 2 quad, or Phenom II X4 (AM3)

Comment: @Razor If he's looking to "get the most money possible with current components", buying 8GB of DDR3 is not a good start. I would suggest getting an AM3 system, saving some money, and buying something top-of-the-line in a newer generation in a couple of years.

Comment: Oh I misread :P

Comment: OMG - Fail!!! hahaha