# What are the consequences of installing DDR3 RAM on a motherboard that only supports DDR2 RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, ddr2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a DDR3 MB compatible with DDR2 RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/75402/is-a-ddr3-mb-compatible-with-ddr2-ram)
>   [would ddr2 memory work in a motherboard with ddr3 standard?](https://superuser.com/questions/318234/would-ddr2-memory-work-in-a-motherboard-with-ddr3-standard)

I just ran into something really weird.

My computer has DDR3 RAM. And the website from my mobo says it only supports DDR2. (I find this out, 2 years after buying the PC)

What are the consequences of this?

And how is this even possible? I thought DDR3 ram had a different shape from DDR2 ram?

Motherboard specs:

[image]

RAM specs:

[image]

Comment: They _are_ shaped/keyed differently. :)  How about some model numbers and such so we know what MB/RAM you are talking about?  Perhaps the manual has a typo (it wouldn't be the first one)?  See [Is a DDR3 MB compatible with DDR2 RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/75402/is-a-ddr3-mb-compatible-with-ddr2-ram) for good info.

Comment: Added specs. :)

Comment: Can you confirm (with an edit) that you are sure you are looking at the right motherboard specs?

Comment: Are you sure you the exactly right MB?  What does the Mainboard tab of CPU-Z show?

Comment: That's not right, I think you think you have a different motherboard then you actually do :).  What does CPU-Z show under the "Mainboard" tab?

Comment: Added screenshot of mobo :)

Comment: It's possible, but would probably require a pair of cutters, hacksaw, glue and a trip to get some more RAM and a new motherboard. Nope, can't actually be done - one part of the provided info is not right.

Comment: Seems like I found the mistake. I missed the little `T` in the mobo's name... that one does support DDR3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your motherboard supports DDR3 RAM. See the manufacturer's page for the [GA-MA790XT-UD4P](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3010#sp).  Your previous link was to the [GA-MA790X-UD4P](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3038#sp).  Note the missing **T** in the second model number.